# Open man section 3

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using Vim to develop C on Linux.
When I press <kbd>K</kbd> in order to open man page for the underlying word, I don't have control on which man section is opened.
Is there a way to specify that somewhere ?

Comment: Wonderful suggestions:
I ended up adding this `set keywordprg=man\ 3\ -s` to my .vimrc

Comment: dont you want different “help” programs for different languages?

Comment: Never needed to launch man from within vim for something other than chapter 3

Comment: You might want to set this keywordprg in a ftplugin so that you keep a working `K` in other filetypes [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#K)

```
  When 'keywordprg' is equal to "man -s", a count
  before "K" is inserted after the "-s".  If there is
  no count, the "-s" is removed.
```

`man -s` seems to be the default for the `'keywordprg'` setting, so simplying using a count before typing <kbd>K</kbd> seems to do the trick.

(Tested successfully with <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and the cursor being on `open`).

Comment: Damn I was 43 seconds too late! :)

Answer (score 9):

From [`:h K`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#K):

```
                            *K*
K           Run a program to lookup the keyword under the
            cursor.  [...]
            Special cases:
            - When 'keywordprg' is equal to "man" or starts with
              ":", a [count] before "K" is inserted after
              keywordprg and before the keyword.  For example,
              using "2K" while the cursor is on "mkdir", results
              in: 
                !man 2 mkdir
            - When 'keywordprg' is equal to "man -s", a count
              before "K" is inserted after the "-s".  If there is
              no count, the "-s" is removed.
```

So <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux, you're likely using mandb's `man`, and you can control the order in which sections are searched. See [`man 1 man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#ENVIRONMENT):

> MANSECT
>   If $MANSECT is set, its value is a colon-delimited list of sections
>   and it is used to determine which manual sections to search and in
>   what order. The default is "1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6
>   7", unless overridden by the SECTION directive in /etc/manpath.config.

So another option is to set in your shell initialisation files:

```
MANSECT=3:3posix:3pm:3perl:3am:1:n:l:8:2:5:4:9:6:7
export MANSECT
```

Or in your vimrc:

```
let $MANSECT="3:3posix:3pm:3perl:3am:1:n:l:8:2:5:4:9:6:7"
```

(Also, depending on what you're programming, section 2 might also need a higher priority.)

(Or, as the manpage says, set system-wide in `/etc/manpath.config`.)

This also works for [FreeBSD's man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=man&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: that is what `-s` does internally

Comment: Indeed, `-s` overrides `MANSECT`.  But this is useful for setting a priority list instead of forcing specific section (which `<count>K` will do), which might be more useful. For example, if `open(3posix)` isn't available, `open(2)` would still be useful (probably more so). `man -s 3 open` would simply ignore `open(2)`.